# Picture component for Material UI CardMedia

Tags: html, reactjs, material-ui, jsx

Material UI has a component for Card and in which for media we have CardMedia. Mui website provides example for image using CardMedia as img component.

https://mui.com/material-ui/react-card/#complex-interaction

I want to utilize picture html tag instead of img, but MUI website doesn`t provide an example for that

I have tried below example, it does generate picture tag but not sure how to source and img tag inside this.

Tried below

```
<CardMedia
          component="picture"
          height="140"
          image="/static/images/cards/contemplative-reptile.jpg"
          alt="green iguana"
        />
```

Want to generate

```
<picture>
  <source srcset="logo-768.png, logo-768-1.5x.png 1.5x" />
  <img src="logo-320.png" alt="logo" />
</picture>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usage of the MUI `CardMedia` `component="picture"` prop/value is not overly documented on the site, but it's [usage can be seen in the MUI tests on Github](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/blob/master/packages/mui-material/src/CardMedia/CardMedia.test.js#L58).

Excerpt from [MUI CardMedia Docs](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-card/#media)

> By default, we use the combination of a  element and a background
> image to display the media. It can be problematic in some situations,
> for example, you might want to display a video or a responsive image.
> *Use the `component` prop for these use cases.*

The [`component` prop](https://mui.com/material-ui/guides/composition/#component-prop) just tells MUI what root element/component it should use as the underlying element for the `CardMedia` component (as opposed to the default `div` element) -- then you provide children as you normally would for that element. (`video`, `picture`, etc.)

Essentially, you'll just set your component prop to `picture` and wrap your `source` and `img` elements as children of `CardMedia` like so:

```
<CardMedia component="picture" height="140">
  <source srcset="https://mui.com/static/images/cards/contemplative-reptile.jpg, https://mui.com/static/images/cards/contemplative-reptile.jpg 1.5x" />
  <img
    src="https://mui.com/static/images/cards/contemplative-reptile.jpg"
    alt="logo"
  />
</CardMedia>
```

Which produces:

[image: example showing devtools inspector]

Working CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-dewdney-e1tuy2?file=/demo.js:410-754

Answer (score -1):

if you want to generate your own cards you would have to write your own code, the whole point of a design system is to use the system. some parts of the MUI library are customizable but not all and this seems to be one of them. you have two options either change your version of MUI or write your own component.

here is a minimal example of how to use the card with image media

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Card from '@mui/material/Card';
import CardMedia from '@mui/material/CardMedia';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Card sx={{ maxWidth: 345 }}>
      <CardMedia
        component="img"
        height="140"
        image="https://api.sandbox.game/experiences/09e61e83-ba95-4368-99b5-f5306ae9d13a/versions/18bdcd8d-ae09-4b45-ae53-858c0b553b41/banner"
        alt="green iguana"
      />
    </Card>
  );
}
```